# Bootstrap-select angular directive not working

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-directive

I am using [bootstrap-select](https://silviomoreto.github.io/bootstrap-select/) by *silvio moreto* with angular. However *selectpicker* has loaded before angular populate the data.

So I am trying to create a directive that will refresh the *selectpicker* itself after angular has populated the data.

Here is the script:

```
(function() {
    'use strict';

    angular.module('myapp')
        .directive('selectPicker', selectPicker);

    function selectPicker($timeout) {
        return {
            restrict: 'A',
            link: function(scope, elem) {
                $timeout(function() {
                    elem.selectpicker('refresh');
                }, 0);
            }
        };
    };

})();
```

I use it in `select` tag as

```
<select ng-model="add.doctype" class="form-control selectpicker with-search" selectPicker data-live-search="true" title="" data-container="body" ng-options="x.tipe for x in ::Doctypes" ng-change="Newdocno()">
    <option value=""></option>
</select>
```

It does not have any effect. Is it something wrong with the directive?

Comment: If you're getting console errors, it's probably because you're missing a single quote on `angular.module('myapp)`

Comment: sorry, updated my question, it is not related to the single quote, no error in console.

Comment: Can you create a JSFiddle?

Answer (score 0):

I have found repository https://github.com/joaoneto/angular-bootstrap-select, however it's deprecated, but can help you.